# (Discord.py) My task isn't working inside my cog, anyone got any ideas?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This task worked perfectly fine when it was in the main file, but I wanted to organise it a little better.
All my other cogs work perfectly fine. No errors show in log when I run the bot, but the task doesn't show.
The task should send a line of text from the text file to a specific channel every 24 hours.

I'm new to cogs, any help is appreciated. :)

```
import os
import asyncio
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

class DQuote(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.dquote.start()

    @tasks.loop(hours = 24)
    async def dquote(self):
        channel = self.client.get_channel(id = 884425493309423646) # send here
        with open('../messages/quo.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8'): # open txt
            txt = file.read()
            spl = list(map(str, txt.splitlines()))
            await channel.send('<@&880059988016504882> ' + random.choice(spl)) # get random quote

    @dquote.before_loop
    async def before_dquote(self):
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(DQuote(client))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not starting it. `dquote.start()` is placed in the `before_loop` method, but `before_loop` is only called *before it starts* (as the name & [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=before_loop#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.before_loop) suggest). As a result it's never actually called because the loop was never started, so `dquote.start()` is never called either.

Put it in the `__init__` method of your cog instead, as the `__init__` is always gonna be called when the Cog is initialized.

```py
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.dquote.start()  # Put it here
    ...
    @dquote.before_loop
    async def before_dquote(self):
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()
        # And remove it down here
```

For more examples about `Tasks` refer to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=before_loop#recipes).

Comment: i have moved it and still get no message sent

Comment: @TGA If you put a `print` as the first line of the loop, does it get printed? Also, tasks don't error the same way commands do, the errors are muffled away silently. If you put a `try/except` around the whole thing, and print the error in the `except` block, does that give you anything? My guess is your filepath is incorrect. Remember you're going from your `main` file that **runs** the bot, **not** the task Cog file.

Comment: changed the file path, it now says in terminal 
```Unhandled exception in internal background task 'dquote'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tgams\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\tgams\OneDrive\Desktop\Bot\events\dquote.py", line 20, in dquote
    txt = file.read()
NameError: name 'file' is not define```

Comment: The error speaks for itself, you never defined `file`. Your `with open()` line should have `as file:` at the end, but there's nothing there. `with open(..) as file:`